# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: JZ002: Password property '' too long. Maximum length is 30

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am getting following error while creating connection using JDBCtemplate.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: JZ002: Password property '' too long. Maximum length is 30.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ002: Password property '' too long. Maximum length is 30.
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:559)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.LoginToken.<init>(LoginToken.java:161)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.doLogin(Tds.java:542)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:484)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:247)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.regularConnect(SybConnection.java:223)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:198)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:132)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:291)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:277)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:259)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:420)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:425)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:434)
```

My spring.xml file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${userName}" />
        <property name="password" value="${passwd}" />
    </bean>
```

i can not change my password as this is UAT environment. Can anybody suggest here any solution. I am using sybase as database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a Sybase restriction - the password can’t be longer than 30 characters. 
If you try a longer password it trims to the first 30 character.
See: [sybase docs for maximum password length](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc74500.1502/html/aserbhp/BHACIAAE.htm)

If the password is externally created then I guess you could do the same and trim the length to 30...